# How can I get the width and height of an Image picked from gallery after cropping in it Image view

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Am trying to get the exact **height** and **width** of a Picture set in an Image, am using cropping [library](https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms) to come out with the Picture/Image place in the `Image` view.

So how can I get its exact selected width and height?

Below is how my code

1. Choosing an Image from gallery, then crop it.

```
private void SelectImageFromGallery(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    new ImageCropper
                    {
                        CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
                        Success = imageFile =>
                        {
                            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            profile_img.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                            var folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);

                            var pathFile = profile_img.Source
                                .ToString().Replace("/data/user/0", "/data/data");
                            File.Copy(imageFile, Path.Combine(folderPath, Path.GetFileName(pathFile)));

                        });
                    }
                }.Show(this);

            }
```

2. Preparing to upload the image (*but I need it's width and height*)

   ```
   // Get the folder path of the cropped Image
   var folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);         

   // Convert it into bytes.
   var readAllBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(folderPath, getPathName));
   // ByteArrayContent.
   var baContent = new ByteArrayContent(readAllBytes);
   ```

According to the code above, is there any way I can get the *Width* and *Height* of an Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the code [here](https://gist.github.com/rudyryk/6d2fb109d2df6873e207) to get the width and and height of the photo:

In your `SelectImageFromGallery`:

```
private async void SelectImageFromGallery(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new ImageCropper
            {
                CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
                Success = imageFile =>
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {

                        ...

                        Size s = GetImageSize(imageFile);
                        Console.WriteLine(s);
                    });
                }
            }.Show(this);

        }
```

Method to `GetImageSize`:

```
 public static Size GetImageSize(string fileName)
        {

            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {
                UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile(fileName);
                return new Size((double)image.Size.Width, (double)image.Size.Height);
            }
            else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {
                var options = new BitmapFactory.Options
                {
                    InJustDecodeBounds = true
                };
                fileName = fileName.Replace('-', '_').Replace(".png", "");
                var resId = Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier(
                    fileName, "drawable", Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName);
                BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(
                    Android.App.Application.Context.Resources, resId, options);
                return new Size((double)options.OutWidth, (double)options.OutHeight);
            }

            return Size.Zero;
        }
```

Comment: Is this method placed in a PCL?, because when I implement it some classes are not resolved such as UIImage , BitmapFactory ?

Comment: @IdrisStack Yes, you can click `show potential fixes` -> `Add reference to Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.Android.dll`.

Comment: @IdrisStack Put your cursor on the UIImage, BitmapFactory.

Answer (score 1):

In the Android environment, one way to do it is with the BitmapFactory class...

```
var options = new Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options { InJustDecodeBounds = true };
Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(FULL_FILE_PATH_HERE, options);
Android.Util.Log.Info("MyApp", $"Width ={options.OutWidth}");
Android.Util.Log.Info("MyApp", $"Height={options.OutHeight}");
```

Comment: The code is not resolved and this is an Android specific code, yet am dealing with both Android and IOS